# Signal conditional for column

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

Reading from yahoo finance download ohlcv for nvidia,
I am creating a column for signal buy/dontbuy, when I try to define which passes the avg>volume test everything either comes out all 'buy' or don't buy.

```
df=pd.read_csv('NVDA.csv',dtype={'label':str})
df['Price%delta']=((df['Close']/df['Open'])*100)                       

df['Avg_volume']=df['Volume'].rolling(7).mean()

df['Signal']=0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Volume'] > row['Avg_volume']:
    df['Signal']='Buy'
    else:
        df['Signal']='Dont Buy'
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Use something like `df['Signal']=np.where(row['Volume'] > row['Avg_volume'],'Buy','Dont Buy')`. Avoid using for loops for this when it can be done in a vectoized way

Comment: @IanQuah Notice how in each iteration OP is just setting the whole series and not every row. Hence he is getting all duplicate values which is either all `Buy` or `Dont Buy` based on his last iteration

Comment: thanks i appreciate your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the for loop at all:

```
mask = df["Volume"] > df["Avg_volume"] 

df.loc[mask, "Signal"] = "Buy"
df.loc[~mask, "Signal"] = 'Don't buy'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying any index where to assign `'Buy'` or `'Don't buy'`. Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row['Volume'] > row['Avg_volume']:
        df.loc[index, 'Signal']='Buy'
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'Signal']='Dont Buy'
```

Comment: it finally worked thank you nixon

Comment: Good to know. Please let me know iI solved it for you by setting the answer as correct.

Comment: Just an FYI - this solution will be considerably slower than the vectorized solution I have posted for larger dataframes.

Comment: I know I'm aware @rahlf23 it can be vectorized, however, given that the user is unaware of how to properly index data, i found more appropriate to give some help on correcting the actual code

Comment: Not saying your answer is incorrect @nixon, it definitely produces the desired output for the OP. Just pointing something out :)

Comment: Yes appreciate the comment, just saying that I find the simpler (although not efficient) solution to be more helpful in this case for OP :)

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized solution using `np.where()`:

```
df['Signal'] = np.where(df['Volume'] > df['Avg_volume'], 'Buy', 'Dont Buy')
```